# How can I develop Windows Phone applications without having an Intel i3/i5/i7 CPU?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, amazon-ec2, windows-server

My school requires me to create a Windows Phone 8.1 project but I have an Intel Core 2 Duo T8300 processor that isn't compatible with the emulator available in Visual Studio and I don't have a Windows smartphone.

How can I solve this problem without buying anything expensive? Are there any open source or freeware Intel Core i3 emulators for Intel Core 2 Duo or unofficial Windows Phone emulators that don't require a specific processor? VirtualBox isn't enough because the virtual machine has the same CPU as my real computer and there is no way to change it. I only want to add the non-standard "SLAT" instruction to my processor, not increase the performance.

If i rent an Amazon EC2 server for a few days, will it be possible to install Visual Studio on it and use the emulator there without any restrictions?

Comment: No.  Talk to your teacher, surely your school has some machines available that allow you to test your app.

Comment: Your school is stupid.  I'd suggest finding another.